# Is every left maximal ideal the annihilator of a simple left module?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, radicals

In my version of *Noncommutative Algebra*, by *Benson Farb & R. Keith Dennis*, in chapter I, section 2 on the Jacobson radical, it is claimed that

> … each maximal left ideal $I$ is the annihilator of some simple $R$-module (namely, $R/I$). This is true because, as stated in Proposition 1.1, simple $R$-modules are precisely $R/I$ for maximal left ideals $I$.

So I believe this is wrong, else every left maximal ideal would be two-sided by the observation far below. Am I missing something?

> How else can we see that for the Jacobson radical as defined by
>   $$J(R) := \bigcap_{\text{simple left $R$-modules $M$}} \operatorname{Ann}_R (M)$$
>   we have $J(R) = \bigcap_{\text{maximal left ideals $I ⊂ R$}} I$, which was the conclusion of this statement?

---

Here is why I don’t think this is true: Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $M$ a left $R$-module.

Then $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$ is a two-sided ideal, because $∀r ∈ R,\, x ∈ \operatorname{Ann}_R (M)\colon$
$$0 ⊂ (xr)M = x(rM) ⊂ xM = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad (rx)M = r(xM) = r0 = 0,$$
and, of course, $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$ as additively closed.

And so any maximal left ideal $I ⊂ R$ would be a two-sided ideal, if this was true.

---

Also, I think that $R = \mathrm{M}_{n×n}(ℤ)$ and $I = \{\big[\begin{smallmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0\end{smallmatrix}\big];\; a,b ∈ ℤ\}$ would yield a counterexample, because $\big[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\big]$ doesn’t annihilate $R/I$.

Comment: Every maximal left ideal is the annihilator of *an element* of a simple module. Your considerations are correct.

Comment: Wow, if it's printed that way, that's a pretty egregious mistake! (No pun intended, egreg :) your answer addresses that mistake really well!) It's true that every maximal ideal $M$ is the annihilator of a simple module because for any maximal left ideal $L$ containing $M$, $R/L$ is simple with annihilator $M$.

Comment: @rschwieb Huh! I missed this comment, (no @ in it). Yes, every maximal ideal is the annihilator of a simple module, but the annihilator of a simple module need not be a maximal ideal: that's where *primitive* ideals kick in.

Comment: @egreg didn’t put an @ because the contents weren’t directed at you (just the joke was)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement that a maximal left ideal is the annihilator of a simple module is incorrect: indeed the annihilator of a module is a two-sided ideal, as you remark, so any maximal left ideal which is not two-sided is a counterexample. Matrix rings provide easy examples of maximal left ideals which are not two-sided.

On the other hand it is true that the intersection of all *primitive* ideals (that is, annihilators of simple modules) is the same as the intersection of all maximal left ideals.

Indeed, any maximal left ideal $I$ is the annihilator of some element of some simple module (in particular, of $1+I\in R/I$). Therefore any maximal left ideal contains a primitive ideal and so
$$
\bigcap\{\text{primitive ideals}\}\subseteq\bigcap\{\text{maximal left ideals}\}.
$$
Conversely, any primitive ideal is the intersection of maximal left ideals, so we get the converse inclusion: indeed, if $I$ is the annihilator of a simple module $S$, then
$$
I=\bigcap_{x\in S}\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)
$$
and $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$ is either $R$ or a maximal left ideal.

Comment: Ah, of course. Any primitive ideal is the intersection of maximal left ideals. That’s it. Thanks!